# Can GLSL produce a *sum* of z-values?

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl, glsles

I'm trying to render a transparent object into a buffer. I'd like to get a rough estimate of the sum of distances from the near clip-plane to each fragment in the mesh, (not just the nearest one). I'm aware of the concurrency issues with reading (a current total) & writing (a new total) to a buffer within a SIMD architecture, yet am trying to find a way to do it.

For the sake of clarity, I'll include some ASCI-art illustrating my problem:

```
   │
┌──┼──┐A
│┌─┼──┘B
│└─┼──┐C
└──┼──┘D
   │
near-clipping plane
```

So, the line represents a single screen pixel, & within that pixel, I'd like to record a value the sum of all the distances: A, B, C, & D. (Rather than just D, as in a normal z-buffer.)

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this using a shader? WebGL would be preferable, but straight OpenGL is an option too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could render with depth testing disables, a shader that emits the fragment depth as fragment color and use additive blending to produce a depth sum output. However most likely want to have the mean value. So you should emit a `vec2(1/2**bit_depth, depth)` so that in one channel the additive blending results in the number of surfaces summed and the other channel you get the sum, so that you can determine the average in a second step.

Comment: Actually, I do want to sum, not the mean. This gives me someplace to start reading, thanks!

Comment: It seems I want depth *testing* ON, but depth *writes* OFF, wouldn't you agree? Here's where I'm reading now: http://www.openglsuperbible.com/2013/08/20/is-order-independent-transparency-really-necessary/

Comment: @Jackalope: If you just want to get the sum value, then if you have depth writes disabled depth testing doesn't matter, because there's nothing changing that could be tested against. The fragment depth is produced regardless.